# Is my understanding about Borel $\sigma$-algebra correct

Tags: borel-sets

Regarding the definition of Borel $\sigma$-algebra, let $\Omega=\mathbb{R}$, $\mathcal{O}=\{(a,b):-\infty < a \le b < \infty\}$,
can I write Borel $\sigma$-algebra: $\sigma(\mathcal{O})$ as $\sigma(\mathcal{O}) = \{ \varnothing,\mathbb{R},\{(a,b)\},\{(-\infty,a]\},\{[b,+\infty)\}\}$ ?

Thanks and regrads

Comment: The Borel $\sigma$-algebra contains far more sets than that. Since all bounded open intervals are in it, it contains all open sets. Hence also all closed sets. But still much more than that: consider [$F_\sigma$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%CF%83_set), [$G_\delta$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%CE%B4_set) and the [Borel hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_hierarchy). It's rather difficult to find a set that is not Borel, but it's [possible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_set#Non-Borel_sets).

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Thanks a lot